# Table rendering with autowidth and scrollX using R package DT

Tags: r, plotly, shinydashboard, dt, flexdashboard

I am having an issue with rendering of the table using the DT package. The table is generated based on clicked events in a plotly plot. I need the table not to span the entire width if there are not enough columns. So as per the vignette, I added the following code to options in the function datatable from DT package:

```
 autoWidth = TRUE,
 columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center'
                                         , width = '200px'
                                         , targets = '_all'))
```

This results in the correct display as desired, on the first click as shown in screenshot Auto-Click1.png (See 1st image). However, if I click on any point the second time, the resulting table spans the full width of the browser. (See Auto-Click2.png or the 2nd image). I would like to have the table displayed as in Auto-Click1 and the rendering to persists between clicks.

To keep the width persistent between clicks, I tried to add the option `scrollX=TRUE`. This helps and the width persists between clicks. But the column headers are now misaligned to the left of the rest of the table. See  ScrollX-True.png (See 3rd image).

Here is a complete reproducible example:

````
    ---
    title: "Dashboard with DT and plotly.  Reproducible example"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: rows
        vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
    ---

    Dashboard
    ======================

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(tidyverse)
    library(tidyselect)
    library(tidyr)
    library(magrittr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(rlang)
    library(DT)
    library(readxl)
    library(writexl)

    ```

    Row 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Plot {.no-padding}

    ```{r}
    data <- mtcars %>%
    rownames_to_column("Model") %>%
    mutate(Make = sub("\\s+.*","", Model))

    ## Plot in the top row
    renderPlotly({
      p <- data %>%
        ggplot(aes(wt, mpg, color = factor(gear))) +
        geom_point() + guides(color=guide_legend("Gear"))
      ggplotly(p,source = "A") %>%
        event_register("plotly_click")
    })
    ```



    Row
    ---------------------------------------


    ### Data Table 

    ```{r tbl}
    renderUI({
      e <- event_data("plotly_click", priority = "event", source = "A")
      chosen_gear <- data %>% 
        pull(gear) %>% 
        unique() %>% 
        sort() %>% 
        .[e[1,"curveNumber"] + 1]

      if(is.null(e))
        return("Click events will appear here")

      DF <- data %>% 
        filter(gear == chosen_gear) %>% 
        dplyr::select(Model, wt, mpg, gear, Make)

      tbl <- DF  %>%
        datatable(rownames = FALSE
                  , extensions = 'Buttons'
                  , options = list(
                    ##scrollX = TRUE, 
                    # Turning the scrollX option on causes Column headers to misalign with rest of the table
                    # Without the scrollX option table has correct width on first click but
                    # On the second click expands to the full width.
                    autoWidth = TRUE
                    , columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center'
                                             , width = '200px'
                                             , targets = '_all'))
                    , dom = "Blrtip"
                    , buttons = list("copy", list(
                      extend = "collection"
                      , buttons = c("csv", "excel", "pdf")
                      , text = "Download"
                    ))
                    , lengthMenu = list(c(5, -1)
                                        , c(5, "All"))
                    , pageLength = 5))

      output$table <- renderDT({tbl})

      DTOutput("table")
    })
````

[Auto-Click1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8yzj.png)

[Auto-Click2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TS0m.png)

[ScrollX-True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uGAQ.png)

Thanks for your help or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/752#issuecomment-575706297 , The easiest way I can think of is *changing the last line from `DTOutput('tbl')` to*

```r
div(style = 'width:500px;margin:auto', DTOutput("table"))
```